# exchange 2010/13 - search mails by category and set them to sensitivity:private

Tags: email, powershell, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I am new to Exchange and we have a requirement where we need to go thru everyones mailbox and look for emails that have been marked by a certain category and set those emails as sensitivity:private. And I have couple of questions on this one:

- Not sure which one is the way to achieve this, should I be using Exchange Management Console - PowerShell script OR Exchange Web Services?
- does anyone have a snippet of searching emails by category and manipulating/editing the email sensitivity to Private?

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use AQS in combination with Exchange Web Services to query by category.

```
  ItemView iv = new ItemView(1000);
  String AQS = "System.Category:red OR System.Category:green";
  FindItemsResults<Item> fiItems = null;
  do
  {
    fiItems = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, AQS, iv);
    foreach (Item itItem in fiItems.Items) {
      Console.WriteLine(itItem.Subject);
    }
    iv.Offset += fiItems.Items.Count;
  } while (fiItems.MoreAvailable == true);
```

See also:

- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/e297b09d-0a69-4a62-8da1-12084df9265f/searchfilter-for-categories-exchange-2010-sp1-ews-managed-api-11?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

To set the Sensitivity, use the `item.Sensitivity` property and then save the item:

```
  item.Sensitivity = Sensitivity.Private;
  item.Save();
```

See also:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633648(v=exchg.80).aspx

Since EWS is just a Managed library, you can also call these methods from Powershell. I'm not sure if there are existing Powershell cmdlets available to do the same type of manipulations, but this would work.